# Assigning Concrete map to Generic typed Map

Tags: java, generics, generic-list

I have `TaskVO` as Base class. 
I have `TaggingTaskVo` which extends `TaskVO`

Below are my two Map declaration, first version is using Generic and second version is specialized.

```
Map<String, List<? extends TaskVO>> genericTaskVoMap = new HashMap<String, List<? extends TaskVO>>();
Map<String, List<TaggingTaskVo>> taskVoMap = new HashMap<String, List<TaggingTaskVo>>();
```

Why can't I assign taskVoMap to genericTaskVoMap ?

```
genericTaskVoMap = taskVoMap;     //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<String,List<TaggingTaskVo>> to Map<String,List<? extends TaskVO>>
```

However when I assign type list to each other it does not complain.

```
List<? extends TaskVO> genericTaskVoList = new ArrayList<>();
List<TaskVO> taskVoList = new ArrayList<TaskVO>();
genericTaskVoList = taskVoList; //No compilation error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another wildcard to perform the assignement:

```
Map<String, ? extends List<? extends TaskVO>> genericTaskVoMap = new HashMap<String, ? extends List<? extends TaskVO>>();
```

Comment: Something little bit strange because I know it's going to be List then why use wildcard for "? extends List"

Comment: This has to do with the principle of nested wildcard, check this website http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html#Nested_Wildcards "Capture conversion applies only on top level wildcards, not on nested wildcards."